# How to redirect subdomain locally on my computer without modifying the code?

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, subdomain

How to redirect subdomain locally on my computer without modifying the code?

Let's say, subdomain 'static.company.com' should be redirected to 'localhost/static'.

**Edit**

I forgot to mention that I had WAMP installed. WAMP already have 'alias directories' that do exactly what I needed - redirect URI to the folder on local server. There is a command-line interface where you should set URI (in my case, multimedia) and /path/to/the/folder/on/the/server/.

You can find this post http://www.itsananderson.com/2009/01/wamp-alias-directories/ useful also if your URI doesn't have slash(/) at the end.

Comment: /etc/hosts file plus a little Apache configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would either need an entry on your local DNS server or an entry in your machine's host file to point to itself.

As for Apache you could simply setup a mod_rewrite rule to transform the URL when it comes in.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/

Comment: I've added line "static.company.com 127.0.0.1" to hosts and restarted machine. When I go there (`http://static.company.com`) it is not redirected at all. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What does a DNS query of "static.company.com" return?  It should return 127.0.0.1.  You still have to make Apache changes that I mentioned to get Apache to serve the right resource.

Comment: should be reversed like so: `127.0.0.1 static.company.com`. Good! Now I am going to configure Apache..

Comment: Not sure this is correct: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^static.company.com[nc]`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/static.company.com/$1 [r=301,nc]`

Comment: This two lines should be added to the server configuration (not to .htaccess) `ProxyPass /multimedia http://localhost/static.company.com/multimedia`
`ProxyPassReverse /multimedia http://localhost/static.company.com/multimedia`

Comment: You should use a hosts file rather than DNS - a DNS to 127.0.0.1 will redirect to whichever computer makes the request, but I think here you just want to redirect requests FROM the host running the web server back to the host.  So just use the hosts file.

Comment: @dunxd True, I was mentioning DNS in the event you setup a static or pseudo-static IP address for your local machine.